# Should stop statement be used in modern fortran codes?

Tags: fortran

My code is something like this and I am thinking of using `stop` statement. At a particular do loop, if a condition is found true then the program should write error message and return to calling main program skipping everything below that do loop.

```
subroutine abc
.....statements, loops, etc.
  do !fifth do loop
...
...
    if (condition is true) then
        write error message and 
        completely get out of subroutine to caller program
    end if
..more if statements
....

  end do

expressions
....
more do loops 

end subroutine abc
```

GNU fortran compiler supports `stop` and `error stop` statements as per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-2008-status.html.

However, Chapman's book (fortran 95/2003 for scientists and engineers, 3rd ed., pp 323) strongly advise against using `STOP` statements in any subroutines.

On the other hand, using a a flag to check execution of remaining every do loop may be even worse. It would be meaningless if an error flag is passed to calling program and subsequent execution of code is allowed.

Update: What if the code has parallel parts?
Any suggestions?

Comment: If the program needs to stop provided there are no other considerations (e.g. parallelism) use stop

Comment: Is there a command other than `stop` to exit a subroutine early?

Comment: If by "parallel parts" you consider Fortran's image model, then error termination (`error stop`) on one image forces error termination on all other images.  Other parallel models are beyond what Fortran says.

Comment: Separate to whether STOP should or should not be used, check out the RETURN statement.

Comment: Here, RETURN will do the same function as STOP.

Comment: I am voting to close this as opinion based. IMHO `stop` is just fine and handy in times. The book has another opinion. You must decide.

Comment: Note: with stop, you can return an exit code to the shell.

Comment: My opinion is that STOP (and ERROR STOP) are fine to prematurely exit a program. I would generally avoid it as the last line in the main program, which was common usage in decades past. I will also note that STOP is being extended in Fortran 2015 to allow you to ask that the implementation not display any message when a STOP is executed.